# Excel VBA & VB6 Printer

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I have the following code, this code was written in VB6 but i can not open the form or check any references.

```
Private Sub PopulatePrinterCombo(cmbDestination As ComboBox)
  Dim objPrinter  As Printer 'a printer in the Printers collection object

  'Add the printers to the combo box
  For Each objPrinter In printers
    cmbPrinter.AddItem objPrinter.DeviceName
  Next

  'Set current selection to the default printer
  cmbDestination.Text = Printer.DeviceName
End Sub
```

I am currently copying the code onto Excel VBA macro, the problem is the   `Dim objPrinter  As Printer`  code, i keep getting an error message saying "USER DEFINED TYPE NOT DEFINED", do i need a reference to add on VBA to be able to get the option of declaring a variable as a "Printer" or something?

My second question is that i do not fully understand the "Printers" in the line  `For Each objPrinter In printers`, what is "Printers"? can someone please explain that to me.

Thank you

**PART 2**

I am now trying to print files, i have the following as my code:

```
  'Initialize values
  intDraftsPrinted = 0
  If objDraftPaths.Count > 1 Then

  Else
    intSelectedDraftCount = CountSelectedDrafts
  End If

  'prompt user to make sure
  intMsgBoxResponse = MsgBox("You selected " & intSelectedDraftCount & " part numbers. After removing duplicates" & vbNewLine & "there were " & objDraftPaths.Count & " unique draft files found." & vbNewLine & "Do you want to print these files?", vbYesNo, "TD Printer")

  If intMsgBoxResponse <> vbYes Then
    intSelectedDraftCount = 0 'So the following for loop will not entered
  Else
    intSelectedDraftCount = objDraftPaths.Count
  End If

  For i = 1 To intSelectedDraftCount

    booSuccess = False

    'open the draft file
    Set objDraftDocument = OpenSolidEdgeDraft(objDraftPaths.Item(i))
    If objDraftDocument Is Nothing Then
      'could not open file
      MsgBox "Could not open the following draft file:" & vbNewLine & _
             objDraftPaths.Item(i), vbExclamation, "Solid Edge Error"
    Else
      'Print the draft file
      For Each objSheet In objDraftDocument.Sheets
        strSheetSize = DetermineSheetSize(objSheet)
        If strSheetSize <> "" Then
          'Determine orientation
          If InStr(1, strSheetSize, "90") <> 0 Then
            'Print as landscape
            intOrientation = vbPRORLandscape

          Else
            'Print as portrait
            intOrientation = vbPRORPortrait
          End If
          'Specify Sheet Size
          Select Case Left(strSheetSize, 1)
            Case "A"
              intPaperSize = VBRUN.PrinterObjectConstants.vbPRPSLetter
            Case "B"
              intPaperSize = VBRUN.PrinterObjectConstants.vbPRPS11x17
            Case "C"
              intPaperSize = VBRUN.PrinterObjectConstants.vbPRPSCSheet
            Case "D"
              intPaperSize = VBRUN.PrinterObjectConstants.vbPRPSDSheet
            Case "E"
              intPaperSize = VBRUN.PrinterObjectConstants.vbPRPSESheet
            Case Else
              intPaperSize = VBRUN.PrinterObjectConstants.vbPRPSLetter
          End Select

          'Enable error handling
          On Error Resume Next

          'Activate the current sheet
          objSheet.Activate
          If Err Then
            'Could not activate sheet
            MsgBox "An error occurred while attempting to print: " & vbNewLine & objDraftPaths.Item(i) & vbNewLine & "The error was:" & vbNewLine & "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Solid Edge Error"
            Err.Clear
          Else
            'Print to the printer specified by the combo box
            objDraftDocument.PrintOut cmbPrinter.Text, 1, intOrientation, intPaperSize, , , , igPrintSelected
            If Err Then
              'Could not print document
              MsgBox "An error occurred while attempting to print: " & vbNewLine & objDraftPaths.Item(i) & vbNewLine & "The error was:" & vbNewLine & "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Solid Edge Error"
              Err.Clear
            Else
              booSuccess = True
            End If
          End If

          'Disable error handling
          On Error GoTo 0

        End If
      Next

      'Close the file
      objDraftDocument.Close False

      intDraftsPrinted = intDraftsPrinted + 1

    End If

  Next i

  'Dereference objects
  Set objSheet = Nothing
  Set objDraftDocument = Nothing
  'Set objDraftPaths = Nothing

  PrintSelectedDrafts = intDraftsPrinted
```

Now the problem comes when i hits the line that says: `intOrientation = vbPRORLandscape`
in excel VBA, it does not recognize "vbPRORLandscape" as well as the next line "vbPRORPortrait". Is there a way to fix that?

Also, i have a feeling that `VBRUN.PrinterObjectConstants.vbPRPSLetter` and the rest of those lines might not work out as well. It works in VB6 though.

Thank you

Comment: Google for : `application.printers excel` to see how other people are dealing with this. Application.printers does not exist in Excel. There is no equivalent. Most people are using the WinAPI to get the list of printers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the `Printers` Collection is available in the MS Access VBA environment but I do not believe it is intrinsic to the *Excel* VBA environment.

I use the WshNetwork object of ***Windows Script Host*** to list the available printers. I use the subroutine below to populate a ComboBox with the list of printers that are connected to the system. In order for this code to work you will need to add the "Windows Script Host Object Model" reference to your VBA project. (Menu: Tools > References [Select from list])

I added the (j) loop to alphabetize the list.

```
Sub populatePrintersList()
    Dim nwo As New WshNetwork
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim bAdd As Boolean

    bAdd = True
    cmbPrinter.Clear
    For i = 0 To (nwo.EnumPrinterConnections.Count / 2) - 1
        For j = 0 To cmbPrinter.ListCount - 1
            If nwo.EnumPrinterConnections(i * 2 + 1) < cmbPrinter.List(j) Then
                cmbPrinter.AddItem nwo.EnumPrinterConnections(i * 2 + 1), j
                bAdd = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If bAdd Then cmbPrinter.AddItem nwo.EnumPrinterConnections(i * 2 + 1): bAdd = True
    Next i

    cmbPrinter.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

---

**Part 2:**

MSDN contains reference material for the `Worksheet.PrintOut` method: [`Worksheet.PrintOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196840(v=office.15).aspx)

In depth documentation for the methods and properties of the `Worksheet.PageSetup` object can also be found on MSDN:  [`Worksheet.PageSetup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174261(v=office.11).aspx)

I suggest using these resources to find a plethora of answers.

Comment: That code worked perfectly, but now my next step has an error. Can you please take a look at "PART 2" above in the question. Thanks